# Display button doesn't show anything even if I did everything correctly (I think)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I never worked with WPF or designing interfaces. I have been learning C# for a while and now I'm trying to make a program for school. We had to build a console project, but I'm trying to build one in WPF so I learn something new today.

I've read some tutorials and websites and that's how I think it is working. But when I click on Calculate, nothing happens.

For now I've begin by displaying the input from that text. After that I have to do the real programming, extracting the a,b numbers from the input, etc.

But for now I want to display the text so I know it works.

Here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="mate.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mate"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Calculator radacini" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Calculator radacini - Octavian Niculescu, 11C" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Proxima Nova Alt Rg"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="f:[a, b] -> R, f(x) = ln x - x + 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Proxima Nova Alt Rg"/>
    <Image x:Name="grafic_functie" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="205" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="343" Source="Untitled.png"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="input" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Introdu a, b, intregi" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="0,71,0,0" FontFamily="Proxima Nova Alt Rg"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Calculeaza radacinile!" Margin="0,0,0,45" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="155" FontFamily="Proxima Nova Alt Rg"/>
</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace mate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string str;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            str = input.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }

        private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Why does pressing on that button doesn't display anything?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `Click = "Button_Click"` event to your button tag too.